# Barras de Rolagem do dataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms

A opção `ScrollBars` está como `Both`, mas não estão aparecendo de jeito nenhum. Nem tenho código para exemplificar. Alguem já passou por isso?

Estou carregando um `datagridview`, mas não estão aparecendo as barras de rolagem.

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico em relação a sua dúvida e também citar algum exemplo?

Comment: Só aparece a barra horizontal se tiver conteúdo para os lados. Se não, ela não é exibida.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, quando algumas colunas estão congeladas ("frozen") as scrollbars porem não aparecer. Veja se alguma das colunas está "frozen". Use a imagem abaixo como referência (retirada de uma resposta similar na stack overflow em inglês):

[image: Colunas FROZEN]

Apenas as colunas totalmente da esquerda podem ser *frozen* e, além disso, pelo menos uma das colunas não *frozen* precisam, obrigatoriamente, estar visíveis.